# Should I edit a bad answer even with permission?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

I saw an accepted answer I gave over a year ago and, beneath that, was another answer with four upvotes (compared to my 43). However, that answer is horribly misguided, misinformed and opinionated. So I said so in the comments and the author of that answer stated it was OK with him if I edited his answer.

However, I don't think it's my place to do so. I could add comments about why it is wrong but that would be too long. I don't know if flagging it for moderator attention is appropriate either.

Other than downvoting the answer, should I edit it?
Or what else can be done?

Comment: I was going to suggest writing a somewhat more constructive comment with some justification of why you think it's misleading - but I see you've done that and deleted your previous comment - kudos. I'd say you've done your bit. One option could be to engage them in chat and discuss your concerns and work together to thrash out an improved answer - since the OP doesn't seem overly concerned though - I'd just move on.

Comment: @JonClements I forgot about chat. I should have done that but, yes, I think I'll move on. Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier to discuss the specifics of the situation if we had a link to the answer.

Comment: Just edit if you are sure. Ask for permission in comments, or the edit comment. Improve the number of useful answers on this site, even if it goes against the unicorn-coins gaming rules. Worst that should happen is your edit gets rolled back... imho

Answer (score 21):

If you see a way to make it a useful answer, comment how that could be acomplished. (Just duplicating info in an existing answer is unlikely to be useful though. And yours is presumably pretty good and exhaustive).
If it's wrong, comment why it's wrong. At least a few short hints should fit, you can even use links to the details, like to your own answer.
If it's not useful, downvote.

Otherwise, you are welcome to improve that answer with edits, but there's a difference between improving a post, taking over a post and replacing a post.
And there's no way we can say where on that scale a good enough edit falls without examining the edit or at least the post.

Comment: *"Just duplicating info in an existing answer is unlikely to be useful though."* - In the case where this is *all* that can be done (because there's literally no unique useful content in the answer and the errors it contains render it irreparably worthless), consider asking the answerer to delete their answer, rather than letting bad content linger around. They make take such a request poorly, but that's on them. If they refuse, there's not much more you can do besides vote.

Comment: +1. The idea behind StackOverflow is the best comments get voted up, thus receiving the most visibility. For every good answer there are a few mediocre ones, and some downright incorrect ones. It is pointless to edit them all with essentially duplicate information. Leaving some feedback in a comment is the best way to go.